# How can I mark 'Best Answer' through ConnectApi?

Tags: feeditem, connect-api, feedcomment

How do I mark an answer as Best Answer through ConenctApi? I tried setting `bestAnswerId` of `ConnectApi.QuestionAndAnswersCapabilityInput` but it does not mark the answer as Best Answer.

```
ConnectApi.QuestionAndAnswersCapabilityInput questionAndAnswerCapabilitiesInput = new ConnectApi.QuestionAndAnswersCapabilityInput();
questionAndAnswerCapabilitiesInput.bestAnswerId = feedComment.Id;
```

Can someone help how to post the answer as Best Answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use ConnectApi.QuestionAndAnswers.updateQuestionAndAnswers after this.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_ConnectAPI_QuestionAndAnswers_static_methods.htm?search_text=bookmark#apex_ConnectAPI_QuestionAndAnswers_updateQuestionAndAnswers_1

`ConnectApi.QuestionAndAnswersCapability result = ConnectApi.QuestionAndAnswers.updateQuestionAndAnswers(communityId, QuestionId, bestAnswerId);`